# Selenium unable to establish secure connection?

Tags: python, selenium, security, connection

**Set-up**

I have a list of housing ads I want to contact automatically using Selenium.

I'd like Selenium to load the housing ad, click the contact button and subsequently fill the contact form

---

**Problem**

The code,

```
url = 'https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/1168063090.htm?ca=21_s'
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.implicitly_wait(60)
browser.get(url)

# click blue contact button 'Envoyer un email'
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="adview"]/aside/div/div[1]/div/a[1]').click()
```

The ad opens, everything seems to be ok (I can see the full ad) but Chrome stays stuck in 'Establishing secure connection...'.

After a very long time I receive a `TimeoutException: timeout: cannot determine loading status`.

I've also tried to find the element by,

- css selector: `'#adview > aside > div > div.box-grey-light.mbs.align-center > div > a.button-blue.large.trackable'`
- class name: `'button-blue'`

but to no avail.

The element I try to locate is the large blue button on the right side of the ad, stating 'Envoyer un email'.

What is going on?

---

**Screenshot**

[image]

Comment: Which WebElement are you exactly trying to locate? Do you mean the `Envoyer un email` button? Thanks

Comment: See end question, I added it for you.

Comment: Can you provide a snapshot when `Chrome stays stuck in 'Establishing secure connection...'.` Thanks

Comment: Added. See question.

Comment: There seems an issue with the website `https://www.leboncoin.fr/locations/1168063090.htm?ca=21_s` in sending `document.ready` state = `complete` to `Selenium`. So would you be willing to wait for a definite time span to click on `Envoyer un email` button? Thanks

Comment: Depends on how long that time span is. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Yeap, I am thinking of a strategy for you but I need to confirm your requirement first. Thanks

Comment: Awesome. Well, if you cannot circumvent, 30sec per page max and the less the better. But would be great if you can circumvent.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To locate the blue button on the right side of the ad, stating 'Envoyer un email' you can use the following line of code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//section[@id='adview']//a[@class='button-blue large trackable']").click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Same issue, stuck in loading. I don't think the issue is finding the element but to understand why it stays stuck in loading. But I'd be happy to know otherwise.